# TextField with labelText on right

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to put the label of an TextField on right, but I don't know how.
The text is ok, but the problem is about the label.

```
          TextField(
            enabled: this.enable,
            enableInteractiveSelection: false,
            autofocus: false,
            textAlign: TextAlign.right,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: this.label,
                hintText: this.hint,
                alignLabelWithHint: true,
                errorText: snapshot.hasError ? snapshot.error : null),
            obscureText: this.obscure,
            controller: _controller,
          );
```

Does someone could help me how to put the labelText  on the right as well?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

you can use [Directionality](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Directionality-class.html).

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _MyHomePageState();
  }
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(30),
              child: Directionality(
                  textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                  child: TextField(
                    textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                    autofocus: true,
                    decoration: new InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: "ایمیل",
                        hintText: "ایمیل خود را وارد کنید"
                    ),
                  )
              )
          ),
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Great help. Works well.

Answer (score 5):

I think the TextField widget doesn't have a property to do that, so you have 2 options:

1-  Create a custom TextField with your custom properties and include a property to align the label text.

2- Remove the label text and use only the hint value, that's pretty common in material design, so your code should be something like this:

```
TextFormField(
                enableInteractiveSelection: false,
                autofocus: false,
                textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: "Hello",
                    alignLabelWithHint: true,
                ),
              )
```